# Hausdorff dimension of the p-adic integers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, fractals

All Cantor sets are homeomorphic, but the [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) of a Cantor set depends on the particular metric being considered.  While there are some special situations where the Hausdorff dimension of a set can be computed easily, in general calculating Hausdorff dimension seems difficult.  I was wondering, however, if the Hausdorff dimension of the set of $p$-adic integers (which forms a Cantor set) is known for each $p$, and if so what a good reference for this would be.

Comment: ... with respect to the $p$-adic norm? The $p$-adic integres are the disjoint union of $p$ copies of itself scaled by a factor of norm $\frac 1p$, hence the dimension should be $1$.

Comment: Hi Hagen.  Yes, I meant the $p$-adic norm; I thought the dimension should be 1, but wanted some confirmation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has been answered by Hagen von Eitzen in the comments:

> The $p$-adic integers are the disjoint union of $p$ copies of itself scaled by a factor of norm $1/p$, hence the dimension should be $1$.